# ThreadPool in backgroundworker to make a crawler

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, web-crawler, httpwebresponse

#### I made a little crawler for a site

Inside a backgroundworker I use threadpool to download multiple pages at same time.

```
        countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(Pages.Count());
        foreach (var t in Pages) {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AnalyzeAndParser), t);
        }
        countdownEvent.Wait();
```

AnalyzeAndParser is a single thread that download a page.
It call a function "HTTP_POSTA" (below)

I make a post, write the body and take the response.

```
        private string HTTTP_POSTA(string Prog, string Avv) {
        HttpWebRequest request;

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxx.it/some.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*";
        request.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.Host = "www.xxx.it";
        request.Headers["Origin"] = "http://www.xxx.it";
        request.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        request.Referer = "http://www.xxx.it/sport";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36";
        request.Headers["XX-Prototype-Version"] = "1.6.0.1";
        request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
        //request.Timeout = 30 * 1000; //Maximum waiting time

        byte[] byteStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("como=1&cod_prog={0}&avv={1}&switch_carrello=sport&_=", Pro, Avv));
        request.ContentLength = byteStr.Length;

        try {
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream()) { 
                stream.Write(byteStr, 0, byteStr.Length);
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
                using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream()) { 
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    return readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to Send URL[A/B] with Prog[" + Prog + "] and Avv [" + Avv + "]", ex);
        } finally {
            if (request != null) { request.Abort(); }
        }

    }
```

But with this design I get a lot of exceptions like:

```
"A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll"
```

I think the problem is in time out, but I'm not sure!

Any suggestion ???
IT's a good design ???

#### More info

This is how I manage exceptions

```
 AnalyzeAndParser(...) {
 ........
 ........
 int err = 10;
 bool go = false;
 while (!go && err > 0) { //Give another try
    try {
      Resp = HTTTP_POSTA(IDChunks[0], IDChunks[1]); 
      go = true;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      err--; 
      if (err == 0) {
         countdownEvent.Signal();
         return;}
    }
  }
  ......
  ......


 }
```

#### StackTree

Message : The operation has timed out

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at G.Form1.HTTTP_POSTA(String Prog, String Avv) in d:\WindowsThings\Dropbox\SinC\Lavoro\Grabber\G\Form1.cs:line 447
```

#### NOTE

If I compile x64 I get less exceptions than x86!

Comment: A full stack trace would be helpful. Add it to your question. Also, if those pages are all from one or a small set of domains, you're going to have trouble because the service point manager won't let you have more than two concurrent requests to the same domain.

Comment: And the inner exception - it looks like there is one (a first chance ecption" is just the wrapper).